# Lwuit Network Connection Timeout issue

Tags: networking, java-me, timeout, lwuit

Sorry for my bad English.

I have download an image from network, i set timeout 2000 milisecond, but timeout not work.
This is my code

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getSource() == okCommand) {
        final Form resultForm = new Form("Result");
        resultForm.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        resultForm.show();
        Label mLabel = new Label();
        ImageDownloadService img = new ImageDownloadService("http://datastore04.rediff.com/h1500-w1500/thumb/69586A645B6D2A2E3131/s47kscdm7r4pjx05.D.0.Happy-Valentines-Day-Wallpaper-Image.jpg", mLabel);
        img.setTimeout(2000);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(img);
        resultForm.addComponent(mLabel);
        Progress progress = new Progress("Loading", img);
        progress.setDisposeOnCompletion(true);
        progress.show();
    }
```

Comment: Well may be you have slow connection, try it using 40 second's timeout

Comment: i try 2 seconds, 0.5 second timeout but it not work

Comment: I am saying to increase the timeout, and you are decreasing it, try it using `img.setTimeout(40000);`

Comment: I mean timeout not work

Comment: then may be some another problem, do one thing, put your code in try-catch block and see if there is any runtime error or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had some issues with getting timeout to work on LWUIT. It should be working with [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) although on J2ME it would be "faked" regardless since J2ME doesn't allow for timeout so we essentially kill the whole thread.